# Connecting to MySQL using encrypted password in PowerShell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am trying to avoid exposing my password on my connection string while connecting to my MySQL DB via PowerShell but I'm getting the error below:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Authentication to host 'endpoint' for user 'my_username' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed.

```bsh
$key = "01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000cb490db2b4c9fa44b669d5aef998b678000000000200000000001066000000010000200000003f506a26c5eeddc7620d8f9714d0ccc48968528840746270eba475f13b70a040000000000e80000000020000200000002d6f515408429f78324bc6b3589056810856bd4570fc61c717464e4f42ce691c2000000071d40064ee52a3222e3bcd64a8115d4ae1a3d6dd0daa64e7eab63fb72d5ce6d74000000034b9e0fe42c8fae724eb374a75e250da714372646099dfa076a2329673797ff3e13aedb1b79edcd2685f03802e40d7a43265fe16419acb238966298eda256567"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $key
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$cn = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$cn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=$mysql_server;DATABASE=information_schema;UID=$mysql_user;PWD=$password"
$cn.Open()
```

Comment: Can you use [integrated authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-authentication-windows-native.html) instead?

Comment: @vonPryz cannot..

Comment: You can't store secure string in a string type of "ConnectionString. Change line 2 to $password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR(convertTo-securestring $key);